# Values not Submitting to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**i am working on view model SalesVM, Click on save button is to submitting the values to Create action...
But when i click to save button, create form reloads and all fields empty..
(Weird for me) thing is that all valuse those i filled in textfields are now in url....!!!??**

Under DOM tab in firebug,,, Error is: Predicted Url:sales/create?SMClientBranchId=1&IsCompleted=true&IsActive=true"

My view code is:

```
    @model SM.CRM.AutosLoan.Models.Core.ViewModels.SalesVM

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Sales", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <form>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RegistrationNumber)

    @Html.DropDownList("SMClientBranchId",IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SMClientBranchId)

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsCompleted)

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)

    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" >Save</button>
    </div>
    </form>
}
```

Controller's create actionspost is....

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IsCompleted, SMClientBranchId, IsActive, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate")] SalesVM salesvm)
{        
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SalesDM salesdm = new SalesDM();
        // save sales info
        salesdm.SMClientBranchId = salesvm.SMClientBranchId;
        salesdm.IsActive = salesvm.IsActive;
        salesdm.IsCompleted = salesvm.IsCompleted;
        salesdm.CreatedBy = "someone";
        salesdm.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.Sale.Add(salesdm);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

**SaleVM:**

```
 public class SalesVM
    {
        #region Public Properties
        public int SMClientBranchId { get; set; }
        public SMClientBranchesDM SMClientBranch { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

**I dont know if its due to wrong submit method or validation problem,,,because form validation is also not working...any reference or help about debugging with firefox will also help...
If some can, please help...Thanks for your time**

Comment: Do you mean when you return the view if `ModelState` is invalid? You need to return the model - `return View(salesvm)`

Comment: You also need to show your model with the validation attributes you are applying.

Comment: thanks for reply..i have put break point on model state but the model state is not executed yet...

Comment: i haven't put any validations except clientbranchid....

Comment: Then why do you have `ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationNumber)` ? and validation messages for the 2 boolean values are a bit pointless. And your model does not even show that you have a validation attribute for `SMClientBranchId`?

Comment: What do your mean _"but the model state is not executed yet"_. Are you not hitting the controller at all? What is the GET method that calls this view. Is it `public ActionResult Create() {`?

Comment: Also you cannot name your `ViewBag` property `SMClientBranchId` since that's already a model property. Change it to (say) `SMClientBranchList` and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SMClientBranchId, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SMClientBranchList)`

Comment: yes, i am not able to hit the action "create",,,

Comment: What is the `</form>` you have at the bottom of the view. This suggests you have a matching `<form>` tag somewhere above. If that inside the `Html.BeginForm()` you have invalid and unsupported html which will definitely prevent the form from posting

Comment: i have these tags perfectly good in actual code,,, i have shorten the code and removed some tags ..my mistake...(removed some references, divs)...

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` tag in addition to the `Html.BeginForm()`? If so its **not** _"perfectly good in actual code"_!

Comment: Base on your edit you need to remove the inner `<form>` tag (nested forms are invalid)

Comment: yes i have sir...and updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you're using 2 `<form>` the first generated by razor `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Sales", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` and the second is the one you've written in this block! try to remove the second one!

```
 @model SM.CRM.AutosLoan.Models.Core.ViewModels.SalesVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Sales", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RegistrationNumber)

@Html.DropDownList("SMClientBranchId",IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SMClientBranchId)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsCompleted)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" >Save</button>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Yes that was also the factor along with some other "foolish" factors,,,,glad you people helped.....Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the related line to this on your View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: Have you check please and update the last status of your code? There is a missing curly brace and you should change **</form>** line to **}**

Comment: no the brace is ok,,, have removed some un-neccessary code for better understanding

Comment: Are you sure? Because there is no start tag **<form>**

Comment: yes i am sure i have shorten the code...but it is in actual code

Comment: Ok, you can shorten the code. But it is better to cut the fields instead of the important sections. So, if you update the code (View) again the problem can be solved more rapidly. Thanks.